# List tables, type of access a specific database user has

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to get a list of all the tables and the rights on them for a specific user at database level, e.g.:

```
User Name    DBName    TableName    Type of Access
=========    ======    =========    ==============
...          ...       ...          ...
```

I have tried using...

```
EXEC sp_helprolemember
EXEC sp_helprotect
```

...and others, but they did not really help me.

I also tried using `sp_msloginmappings` but this failed as I do not have admin rights on the server.

Please suggest me some pointers or examples.

Comment: @ AB....Thanks for editing and making it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert in T-SQL but, this might do what you want hopefully.

```
declare @Proc nvarchar(50)
declare @RowCnt int
declare @MaxRows int
declare @ExecSql nvarchar(255)

select @RowCnt = 1
select @Proc = 'SELECT * from fn_my_permissions'

declare @Import table (rownum int IDENTITY (1, 1) Primary key NOT NULL , TableName varchar(50))
insert into @Import (TableName) select name from sys.Tables

declare @Output table (entity_name varchar(50), subentity_name varchar(50), permission_name varchar(50))

select @MaxRows=count(*) from @Import

while @RowCnt <= @MaxRows
begin
    select @ExecSql = @Proc + '(N''' + TableName + ''', N''OBJECT'') where subentity_name = ''''' from @Import where rownum = @RowCnt 
    insert into @Output exec sp_executesql @ExecSql
    Select @RowCnt = @RowCnt + 1
end

select * from @Output
```

This will give the Permissions for the current user. If you want to find the permissions for a given user then try the following;

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = N'username'
GO

declare @Proc nvarchar(50)
declare @RowCnt int
declare @MaxRows int
declare @ExecSql nvarchar(255)

select @RowCnt = 1

select @Proc = 'SELECT * from fn_my_permissions'

declare @Import table (rownum int IDENTITY (1, 1) Primary key NOT NULL , TableName varchar(50))
insert into @Import (TableName) select name from sys.Tables

declare @Output table (entity_name varchar(50), subentity_name varchar(50), permission_name varchar(50))

select @MaxRows=count(*) from @Import

while @RowCnt <= @MaxRows
begin

    select @ExecSql = @Proc + '(N''' + TableName + ''', N''OBJECT'') where subentity_name = ''''' from @Import where rownum = @RowCnt 
    insert into @Output exec sp_executesql @ExecSql

    Select @RowCnt = @RowCnt + 1
end

select * from @Output

GO

REVERT
GO
```

Of course, just replace username with the login of the user you need to get the permissions for.

You'll also have to specify which database you want to execute this for.

I've restricted the results to the table itself. However, if you remove the;

```
where subentity_name = '''''
```

You can find the Permissions for each Column aswell.

I'm sure there must be a better way of doing this... But, this seems to work anyhow!

Comment: @Gallagher.....This is what i was exactly expecting...Thanks for the example.....Ur an T-SQL Expert....Thanks again

Comment: Thanks for the compliment S! Great that I could help!

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me in the past, tells me what they have access to and what kind of access

```
select princ.name
, princ.type_desc
, perm.permission_name
, perm.state_desc
, perm.class_desc
, object_name(perm.major_id)
from sys.database_principals princ
left join
sys.database_permissions perm
on perm.grantee_principal_id = princ.principal_id
WHERE princ.name = 'USERNAME'
```